# Postgresql time series interval

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

I'm using postgres (RDS) for storing time series data.

Let's say my data look like this:

- timestamp: (Index and partition key)
- source: Integer Index
- data: Binary json contains the data

> ```
> timestamp           | source   |  data
> ---------------------+----------+------------------
>  2017-01-24 19:24:41 |  1       | { some jsonb }
>  2017-01-24 19:25:41 |  1       | { some jsonb }
>  2017-01-24 19:25:41 |  2       | { some jsonb }
>  2017-01-24 19:26:41 |  3       | { some jsonb }
>  2017-01-24 19:32:41 |  1       | { some jsonb }
>  2017-01-24 19:33:41 |  2       | { some jsonb }
>  2017-01-24 19:45:41 |  3       | { some jsonb }
>  2017-01-24 19:50:41 |  1       | { some jsonb }
>  2017-01-24 19:56:41 |  1       | { some jsonb }
>  2017-01-24 20:01:41 |  1       | { some jsonb }
> ```

I would like to sort the data by `source` and to have the data split by interval meaning let's say split by a 15 minutes interval.
I also would like `round` the time when splitting it to interval.

So far I got

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', timestamp) + date_part('minute', timestamp)::int / 15 * interval '15 min' AS fifteen_minutes, data
FROM MY_TABLE
where source=1
GROUP BY data, fifteen_minutes
ORDER BY fifteen_minutes desc
```

Which returns

> ```
> fifteen_minutes      | source   |  data
> ---------------------+----------+------------------
>  2017-01-24 19:15:00 |  1       | { some jsonb }
>  2017-01-24 19:15:00 |  1       | { some jsonb }
>  2017-01-24 19:30:00 |  1       | { some jsonb }
>  2017-01-24 19:45:00 |  1       | { some jsonb }
>  2017-01-24 19:45:00 |  1       | { some jsonb }
>  2017-01-24 20:00:00 |  1       | { some jsonb }
> ```

The issue is that I'm still getting multiple results for each interval. I would like to `distinct` by the interval and get the closest timestamp

Ideally I would like to get: (single result per interval)

> ```
> fifteen_minutes      | source   |  data
> ---------------------+----------+------------------
>  2017-01-24 19:15:00 |  1       | { some jsonb }
>  2017-01-24 19:30:00 |  1       | { some jsonb }
>  2017-01-24 19:45:00 |  1       | { some jsonb }
>  2017-01-24 20:00:00 |  1       | { some jsonb }
> ```

Any better idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Please post the expected output based on the above data

Comment: For one source and any 15-minute bucket, how will you decide which value from "data" to use?

Comment: the "nearest" value for ex'
from `2017-01-24 19:24:41` or `2017-01-24 19:25:41`  => `19:24:41` is closest to 19:15. 
Currently the code is handling this logic by map reducing the results

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct on (fifteen_minutes, source)
    fifteen_minutes, source, data
from (
    select 
        to_timestamp((extract(epoch from timestamp) / (15 * 60))::int * 15 * 60) as fifteen_minutes,
        data, timestamp
    from t
) t
order by
    fifteen_minutes, source,
    abs(extract(epoch from timestamp) - extract(epoch from fifteen_minutes))
```